# WCF - Give Class DataContract during Compile or Runtime

Tags: wcf, datacontract, reflection.emit, mono.cecil, bytecode-manipulation

If I have the code:

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

How do I convert it to the code below at runtime or compile time?

```
[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Can I do this using DynamicProxy? Cecil? or some other open source project?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  There are many other ways to avoid marking up a POCO if it is just the syntax that you don't care for - `XmlSerializer` being one of them.

Comment: Does that have any limitations within WCF by doing it that way? But yes, I also just wanted to know how to do this kind of manipulation even if there is a better/easier way to do it.